# sleep/DispatcherTimer function for textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

How do I set the **Textbox** to sleep for 2 second and within that 2 second it **changes** *from green to red* | after 2 seconds it changes back to green ???

for example:

```
        dropText.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
//Thread.Sleep(2000);
//dropText.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); ????
```

Comment: A [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) is probably the simplest way.  Make sure you [pick the right one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I couldn't use timer in vs2013, I can only use DispatherTimer.

Comment: Windows 8.1 ; creating tablet app ; c#?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Thread.sleep you can use await Task.Delay. That will wait asynchronously and your UI will be responsive during that time.